# Passing data via AJAX responds in NULL values

Tags: php, ajax, slim-3

Passing additional data to my REST server doesn't work quite well.

I have this simple ajax call:

```
// Client
$(document).on('click', '#car', function(e){   
    e.preventDefault();
    var name  = $(this).data('name');    // Tesla
    var model = $(this).data('model');  // X
    $.ajax({ 
        type: "GET", 
        contentType: 'text',
        cache: false,   
        url: "http://server:80/api/v1/cars/" + name,
        data: JSON.stringify({
                "model": model
              }),         
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){ },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){}                      
    });
});
```

The problem is that `model` is always `NULL` on my server whereas `car` is working fine. I also `var_dumped` the whole request and searched for `model` but it is not there unfortunately.

```
// Server
public function show($request, $response, $args)
{          
    $model = $request->getParsedBody()['model']; 
    $name  = $args['id'];

    echo $model;     // NULL
    echo $name;      // Tesla
}
```

I also don't understand why my request URL looks like this under the developement tools in the browser:

```
http://server:80/api/v1/cars/Tesla.txt?{"model":"X"}
```

He puts the JSON at the end of the request url and I think this is not a standard behavior?

Comment: i dont think you can pass data in a TYPe=get   try POST

Comment: @ReubenGomes Changing the type from GET to POST works, but I wonder why. The official documentation isn't really, unfortunately, clear about that. You can make a small post and I will accept your answer. Thank you.

Comment: Magiranu Please check below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Why**

Usually get is a Query String where data is passed through the URL with variables appended to the URL and POST the data is passed through the request body POST can pass more data then GET. in GET everything has to be part of your URL no more data can be added  in  POST all your data has to be sent throught the message body

> as basic as it get

```
Your typical query String : http://example.com/over/there?name=ferret&sname=somethingelse

Yout would use $_GET['name'];

and For POST

URL:http://example.com/over/there
Message Body name=ferret&sname=somethingelse

$_POST['name'];
```

so in php you have something called `$_REQUEST;`
in jave you would use `request.getParameters` which will automatically handle it for you
this `$_REQUEST`  handles both get and POST data

Answer (score 1):

Try just `data:{model:model}` instead of `JSON.stringify({"model": model})`. See more information http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: I tried it but without luck. Thank you for you input Nouphal.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the data in this way, data: {model:JSON.stringify(model)},

```
$(document).on('click', '#car', function(e){   
    e.preventDefault();
    var name  = $(this).data('name');    // Tesla
    var model = $(this).data('model');  // X
    model = JSON.stringify(model);

    $.ajax({ 
        type: "GET", 
        contentType: 'text',
        cache: false,   
        url: "http://server:80/api/v1/cars/" + name,
        data: {model:model},         
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){ },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){}                      
    });
});
```

Comment: my bad i put the edit in the wrong place i forgot my answer was a comment